# Grouped Product - force same quantity for all products

Tags: cart, magento2.3, grouped-products, quantity

I am using **Magento 2.3**.
I have defined 4 different simple products with a price of 3.99 each.

I want to create a grouped product to allow the user to purchase 1 of each product, with a total price of 15.00 (i.e. 3.50 each). I don't want the user to edit the single quantities of each product so that I am sure he buys the **same quantity** of each product.

This same quantity must also be handled in the cart, so that the user cannot edit the quantities from the cart. Probably a grouped product is not the correct choice.

How can I define the product ?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the configurable product is not the right option.

What you should use for this is a bundled product so for example you have:

- simple product A price $2
- simple product B price $3

you need to create a Bundle product, for its configuration under **Bundle Items** you will need to create an option for each product (in this case 2 options) and add the product for each one. I think the best choice is toselect **Multiple select** for the **Input type** and check the **required** checkbox, also be sure that the checkbox **User defined** is not checked (this options does not appear always).

That would be it, you can change the **Input type** of the options if you want (to see which one meet your requirement) also you can select the QTY the user is going to add to the cart for each product.

[image: example]